# Is there a notion of a club set in a partial order?

Tags: set-theory

Is there a notion of a club set in a general partial order?

I know the term [club](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_set) for an ordinal but,
what does it mean that $A$ is unbounded in a general tree of a general well order? (for example [Aronszajn tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronszajn_tree) $\mathcal T$).

$A$ unbounded means that for every $a \in \mathcal T$ there is $b \in A$ s.t. $a<b$?

Thank you?

Comment: Almost: if $\langle P,\preceq\rangle$ is a partial order, a set $S\subseteq P$ is unbounded iff for each $p\in P$ there is an $s\in S$ such that $p\preceq s$. Change $a<b$ in your example to $a\le b$, and it will be fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Wouldn't that usually be called a cofinal set? What unbounded should mean is the negation of bounded, i.e. no $p\in P$ is above every element of $S$.

Comment: @Miha: You’re right, of course; I was thinking more about the OP’s definition than about the term.